# Openshift: Where's KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE on pod/container

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I need to get access to current namespace. I've look up `KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE` and `OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE` but they are unset.

```
$ oc rsh wsec-15-t6xj4
 $ env | grep KUBERNETES
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://172.30.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_53_TCP_ADDR=172.30.0.1
KUBERNETES_PORT_53_UDP_ADDR=172.30.0.1
KUBERNETES_PORT_53_TCP_PORT=53
KUBERNETES_PORT_53_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_53_UDP_PORT=53
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_DNS=53
KUBERNETES_PORT_53_UDP_PROTO=udp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=172.30.0.1
KUBERNETES_PORT_53_TCP=tcp://172.30.0.1:53
KUBERNETES_PORT_53_UDP=udp://172.30.0.1:53
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_DNS_TCP=53
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://172.30.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=172.30.0.1
```

Also the content of `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/namespace` is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: The path is ``/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace``.

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift are using Project instead Namespace.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/architecture/core_concepts/projects_and_users.html#namespaces

It extended features of kubernetes namespace, such as resource limitation, rbac and so on.

Comment: For what they are asking, there is no difference. A project is really conceptual only, in practice the name still derives from the namespace.

Comment: @Graham, You’re right! Thank you for additional information.